# Advice how to implement a simple user login and authenication

Tags: web-services, authentication

We are in the process of building a simple Android application together with a simple back-end web server to allow the user to get some information form the server.

We need to login the user, to make sure he is authorized to view the data, but apart form that I do not think we have particular security concerns.

I need some advice on how we can implement the server to keep things as simple as possible.

For example, we could use something like this to make sure the user is authorized to see the data:

```
 http://ourwebservice/user/password/viewsuchandsuchdata
```

Is that a good way of doing things?

Do you have any suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to secure web-services.

The simplest is possible "Basic Auth" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). On every request, you send the user credentials in the "Authorization" HTTP header concatenated with ":" and base 64 encoded. To keep it safe, you need to make sure the connection to your web-server is using SSL (HTTPS), otherwise the user password could be intercepted.

Another "newer" solution is OAuth2, and in your case the "Resource Owner Credentials" flow. Instead of passing the user credentials on every request, you use them once to "exchange" them for a short-lived access token issued by your server. Then on any request to the web-service you pass that access token in lieu of authentication. The server must then verify that the token is valid and find out for which user it was issued. For more info see this article: http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified.

There are potentially many more "custom" ways of doing authentication...

Going the OAuth2 flow is probably more difficult but there are lots of open-source libraries out there to help you build a OAuth2 provider (http://oauth.net/2/). The advantage is that you don't have to store the user password on the device, which is safer (the less you touch passwords, the better).